# Signal and kill C

Tags: c, unix, signals, kill

I am learning about `signal()` and i have this two files:

server.c:

```
void handler_sigcont(){
  printf("SIGCONT server\n");
}

int main(){
  signal(SIGCONT,handler_sigcont);
  printf("%d\n",getpid());
  kill(getpid(),SIGSTOP);
  printf("server!\n");
}
```

client.c:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  kill(atoi(argv[1]),SIGCONT);
  printf("client!\n");
}
```

First i execute server.c, this is the output:

```
6999

[7]+  Stopped                 ./sobusrv
```

Then i execute client.c like this:

```
./client 6999
```

To wake up process 6999.
The output is the following one:

```
client!
SIGCONT server
server!
[8]   Done                    ./sobusrv
```

But if, in server.c, i change the `signal()` after `kill()`, like this:

```
void handler_sigcont(){
  printf("SIGCONT server\n");
}

int main(){

  printf("%d\n",getpid());
  kill(getpid(),SIGSTOP);
  printf("server!\n");
  signal(SIGCONT,handler_sigcont);
}
```

I get this output:

```
client!
server!
[8]   Done                    ./sobusrv
```

I want to know why the handler is avoided when `signal()` is written after `kill()`.

Comment: You've stopped the process so it doesn't execute the `signal` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the call to `signal()` is written after `kill()` in your server, it means the signal handler won't get installed until after the server receives `SIGCONT`. This is because the `kill()` call in the server takes effect immediately to suspend the server process.

At the point the server receives `SIGCONT`, the default handler will be used, since no other handler has been installed yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's not avoided, but the order of operations is different.  Your server gets a STOP signal before you've registered the handler.  When you send it SIGCONT, it continues, then registers the handler and exits without ever receiving another signal.  The handler will not be executed for signals that occur before the handler is registered.

Answer (score 1):

you can use raise(SIGCONT) function like this:

```
void handler_sigcont(int sig){
  printf("SIGCONT server\n");
}

int main(){
  signal(SIGCONT,handler_sigcont);
  printf("%d\n",getpid());
  raise(SIGCONT);
  printf("server!\n");
}
```